# How to filter columns in SQL Server replication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql, replication

I need to replicate some data from two tables in one database to another databases. I used snapshot replication. The issue is that I would like to replicate only some selected columns and the others should stay with untouched data. I don't want to loose their data. The source of those columns is other system. So I need to replicate only data from my columns. Do anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should the 'untouched data' columns stay untouched at the publisher or at the subscriber?

At the source, vertically filtering the articles works with all replication models, see [Filtering Published Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151775(v=SQL.90).aspx) and [How to: Define and Modify a Column Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146925(SQL.90).aspx).

At the subscriber both merge and transactional replication allow this, if properly initialized, but snapshot replication definitely does not.